# How to update model relationships in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have many to many relationships in ember:

```
MYSPACE.User= Model.extend({
   teams: hasMany('team'),
});
MYSPACE.Team = Model.extend({
    users:       hasMany('user'),
});
```

On the user admin page you can update user teams - add new teams, remove teams etc ... So how I can update user teams?

Imagine you have user with teams with ids [2,3,4]
and you update  user to have teams [2,5,6,7]

We are using ember 1.6

How to do it?

Comment: Are you using Ember Model as your model library?

Comment: I am using Ember data model.  `Model` is  `DS.Model`

Comment: If you're using DS.Model then you're using ember data, so you could reload relationship with user.get('teams').reload(), but I'm not sure in what ember data version reload() is available...

Answer (score 1):

You use `addObject`:

```
user.get('teams').addObject(team);
```

where `user` is an instance of a `user` model and `team` is an instance of `team` model.

If at all possible, you should dump 1.6 and switch to atleast 2.4 with Ember-CLI, asap.

Comment: `addObject` is for add on object. How to remove it? Is I have situation where I have addedd 2 new objects and remove 3 objects what is the best way for update. Are there something like `setObjects` to replace all objects with new ones?

Comment: then you use `removeObject`. You can use any of these functions to manipulate the array: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html